# Unable to see Action property of Image in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I was working on a specific bookmark based exercise of Power BI to learn this feature.

The task is to add an image and on click of this image reset all the slicers on the page of the report.

I could add the reset bookmark, however, I am unable to add mouse hover effect on the image to add click event.
I read somewhere about the action property of image to set to this bookmark.
But, I am not able to see the action property for the image in Power BI.

[image]

[image]

I searched in both of these tabs but I could not find action property.

Am I missing out on anything?
Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Maybe you want to add a [button with an action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-buttons?tabs=powerbi-desktop#select-the-action-for-a-button) and [customize it to show the image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-customize-button?tabs=powerbi-desktop#add-a-custom-image-or-icon)?

Answer (score 0):

i guess that there's a problem with your image. Let me show you how it should look. Try to choose another one

[PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHWpG.png)

If you look at the right there's an option that's Action, and from there you can select the action that you want. In your case should be Bookmark and then choose the Bookmark that you want.

Comment: I am trying to find solution for this exercise. https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/power-bi/exercises/power-bi-desktop/bookmarks/4514/ The image is provided in the link above. Its in png format. Is the issue with the format? Which type of image are you using here?

Comment: Is it a version problem? I am using Power BI Desktop 2.99 64-bit version (Nov 2021).

Comment: The image that i used it's a .png. I was looking some documentation and the version   seems to be the problem -> 

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/November-2021-release-how-to-add-action-to-button-and-images/m-p/2194251#M803434

You can download and update your PowerBI version from here -> 

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/

Let me know if this solves the issue!

Comment: I have raised the request for upgrade to our IT. Once its done, I will try and will update here. Thanks!